# Stop Firebase Function If Error Was Thrown

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm building fairly lengthy firebase cloud functions, and to make the code more readable, I'm splitting some verifications into different files.

For instance, when a user wants to make a change, I check whether their account status is set to `activated`. I offload that logic into a separate `authFunctions.js` file, and if the user does not pass, I throw an error directly from within the `authfunctions.js` file.

I've just noticed however that throwing the error from this imported file doesn't stop the calling function from proceeding, and hence a user is able to bypass the security.

**index.js**

```
exports.setDraftOrganisation = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    // Check if user's account is not disabled (or pending info confirmation)
    authFunctions.validateUserAccountIsActive()

    // Proceed with operation
    updateData()
})
```

**authFunctions.js:**

```
exports.validateUserAccountIsActive = async function() {    
    if(verificationFailed) {
        const functions = require('firebase-functions')
        functions.logger.error(`User's account is not activated`)
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition')
    }
}
```

Is there any elegant way to not halt the main function if the imported function signals a blocking issue? I was thinking of maybe using `try {} catch(){}` in the main function, but that would add a lot more lines of code in the main function effectively defeating the purpose of moving the logic into `authFunctions.js`.

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that your function is async and you're ignoring the promise that it returns.  Ignoring promises is a good way to introduce bugs in Cloud Functions code.  All promise should be waited before sending a result.

Comment: You're correct. I have just came back to this thread wanting to post an update after figuring out the issue. The problem was that I wasn't waiting for `validateUserAccoutnIsActive` to resolve the promise. If I call the function as `await authFunctions.validateUserAccountIsActive()` then it works. Thanks for your help.